# How can I edit files in a Docker container from an editor on my host?

Tags: image, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-container

I'm new here, so appreciate your patience with my question.

I have a container which has 5 folders with files that I want to modify via Visual Studio Code outside the container, not with Nano or any other editor in the container itself.

I've seen many recommendations to mount a volume. How can I go about trying that?

Comment: If you mount the volume you can do everything with it on the host side.

Comment: You don’t directly edit files in containers: your changes will be irretrievably lost as soon as the container exits.  Edit the source code that builds the image, re-run `docker build`, and `docker run` a new container with the new image.

Answer (score 0):

Map the host folder to a folder mounted in the image.
`docker run -it -v /hostdir:/dockerdir 'imageName'`.
Now you can put all the folders in dockerdir or mount them all and work on the files from outside the container.